# Prove that the sum of a certain infinite series is 1

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics, mp.mathematical-physics, co.combinatorics

Prove the (numerically-evident) proposition that 
\begin{equation}
\Sigma_{i=0}^\infty f(i) = 1,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f(i)= 2^{-4 i-6} q(i) \frac{\Gamma(3 i+\frac{5}{2}) \Gamma(5 i+2)}{3 \Gamma(i+1) \Gamma(2 i+3) \Gamma(5 i+\frac{13}{2})}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
q(i) = 185000 i^5 +779750 i^4 +1289125 i^3 +1042015 i^2 +410694 i+63000=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
i (5 i (25 i (2 i (740 i+3119)+10313)+208403)+410694)+63000.
\end{equation}
This is the special case ($\alpha=0$) of eqs. (4)-(6) in [arXiv:1301.6617](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6617), and eqs. (2)-(3) in [arXiv:1303.1125](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1125).

Comment: Is this a cry for help or an invitation to a contest?

Comment: Have you tried the Gosper-Zeilberger algorithm for summing hypergeometric series?

Comment: can you give some background how this identity to unity arises? does that suggest a way to a proof?

Comment: Then too, some numerically evident propositions are false...  For example,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(3n-2)!}{(2n)!} \frac{(2n+99)!}{(3n+99)!}
$$
is not quite equal to what numerical computation suggests.  See
http://math.harvard.edu/~elkies/Misc/sol11.html .

Comment: Denominator 16 ... maybe it is somehow related to these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula 


Comment: The series arose in an effort to answer what would seem to be a quite fundamental quantum-information-theoretic question--that is, what proportion (in terms of Hilbert-Schmidt measure) of (the simplest form [two-qubit]) of quantum states are not entangled (i. e. separable)? For the standard (15-dimensional) set of such states, the formula, transforming $i$ to $i+1$ yields, 8/33 (again, to arbitrarily high precision).

Greater elaboration/motivation can be found in the two arXiv preprints indicated in the original posting. (Reference to the Zeilbeger algorithm is given in the first of these.)